# Отмена кеширования HTML, PHP

Tags: php, html

у меня проблема.

Я пишу сайт и постоянно добавляю новые элементы и возникает потребность в HardRestart, то-есть перезагрузкой, которая удаляет кеш (Shift + F5), и ведь я-то знаю что и как нужно сделать, чтобы увидеть результат обновления, но пользователь - нет и не должен, а на смартфонах вообще молчу.

Так вот, как такое исправить, подскажите пожалуйста.

Версия HTML - 5, PHP - 7.

Comment: Указать нужные параметры кеширования в HTTP-заголовках Cache-Control и Expires

Comment: @andreymal, можно пример, где именно писать? В htaccess или php?

Comment: Это уже сами решайте, где вам удобнее писать. Главное чтобы браузер получил эти заголовки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Одного решения для этой проблемы нет. 
Т.к. мой движок самописный - я сделал так, что все файлы .css подгружаются в один большой тег style. То-то и всего.

Answer (score 1):

Большинство браузеров `HTML` контент не кешируют, кешируют в основном `js`, `css` и прочие. Что бы предотвратить это.
Для `HTML` можно отдавать в заголовках

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Для медия контента `js, css, img, fonts` сложнее, браузеры могут игнорировать `header` заголовки, лучше при смене содержимого менять URL, добавить например версию. 
Например

```
/media/static.01.js
/media/style.css?v=01
```

Сменился контент, сменили версионость

```
/media/static.02.js
/media/style.css?v=02
```